# SPRING-BOOT enabling HSTS results in o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor : Error parsing HTTP request header

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, hsts

I need to enable HSTS in my Spring-boot application, after adding suggested code (helped by stackoverflow) when i make a https call I get
o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

Spring-boot version 2.7.13

properties:
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2`

I have added in a configuration class:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{

    http.headers()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
            .requestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE)
    ;

    return http.build();
}
```

When I try
https://localhost:8086/hello

it yields
`

```
2023-08-09 10:45:30.408 DEBUG 19368 --- [nio-8086-exec-3] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [  üïs©K~8>LØÒHÙT·án%K>J¸´(ØÄ ÿDè¸N¶AÈ|âY`hdéKwô¬ý|jð  ÊÊÀ+À/À,À0Ì©Ì¨ÀÀ   / 5 úú      
 
   3 + )     éÚU}gËXô#¸Ù5¡úZºLUá]ÿ¥ijÒ[ - ÿ           Di  h2    #           localhost   hhttp/1.1êê    Ì                                                                                                                                                                                                            ]
2023-08-09 10:45:30.408 DEBUG 19368 --- [nio-8086-exec-3] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x020x000x010x000x010xfc0x030x030xefs0xa9K~0x168>L0xd80xd2H0x0c0xd90x0c0x9aT0xb70xe1n%K>J0xb80x110x170xb40x07(0xd80xc4 ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:407) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
```

`
the same http request
http://localhost:8086/hello

works as expected. Note that I have no http redirection, at some point I will add

```
http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
```

as I do not want `http` support.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly add the HSTS header. If you use spring security there are some security headers added to your applicaiton by default. In those default headers HSTS is present.
Reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/headers.html#headers-default

Comment: I only added 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

in Order to get HSTS headers.

DO I need to add a HTTP redirect ?

Comment: No, the spring boot starter security is more than enough.

Comment: Can you send me more code snippets of your project , so that we can easily debug it

Comment: Thanks for the help - solved . There was a TOMCAT setting that meant http traffic so my https request was not processed.